# Strange behaviour of CPU balance in t2.2xlarge AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a t2.2xlarge AWS EC instance that we use as a Remote Desktop Server.  Most or the workload on this instance takes place in weekdays from 08:00 to 18:00.  We expected our CPU balance to go down during business hours and to go up during nights and weekends.

The t2.2xlarge instance has a baseline CPU of 135%, so since it has 8 vCPUs, the baseline system CPU utilization should be 135/8 = 16.875%

However, we are seeing a strange behaviour on nights, CPU balance not always grows in spite of CPU utilization being at the lowest, well below the 16.875% baseline.  For example, see these monitoring graphs for CPU Utilization, CPU credits and CPU balance for the last 24 hours:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the lowest CPU utilization and CPU credit usage for the instance take place during 23:00 and 6:00, but it spite of that, the CPU balance during that period of time is flat, when we expected it to grow a lot faster than it grows from 18:00 to 23:00.

Why does that happen? What should we do to have the instance gain CPU credits during the periods of very low activity?

Comment: I believe this to be the exact same scenario as the other question.  The algorithm is fair and works as documented, but you get a different impression and the graphs don't seem right, until you understand one of the implications.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I was really puzzled by the behavior.